# How to pass a parameter form perl in linux expect script?

Tags: linux, perl, shell, expect

I have to pass a path at runtime as the abc.sh script will prompt for it .. I am trying  following expect script to accomplish this,

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set force_conservative 0  
if {$force_conservative} {
    set send_slow {1 .1}
    proc send {ignore arg} {
        sleep .1
        exp_send -s -- $arg
    }
}
spawn abc.sh
match_max 100000
expect -exact "Please enter path : "
send -- $path
expect -exact "\r
expect eof
```

Need your help – how I can pass $path values at run time calling like this ?

```
expect script.exp $path
```

Thanks,

Comment: If i understand the question correct, you want to call that exp script with a path variable like in your last line from within a perl script? Assuming you have the path stored in a variable `$path` within your perl script, i suppose you look for `system "expect script.exp $path";`? Or something completely different. Or do you want to replace the exp script with a native perl script? In that case http://search.cpan.org/~rgiersig/Expect-1.15/Expect.pod is your friend.

Comment: yes DeVadder thanks, yes i am looking for system "expect script.exp $path";

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Expect Answer**

Use `send -- $argv` in your `expect` script because `$argv` holds the command line arguments.

As an example, I've this handy expect script that interacts with `ssh` commands when admins stupidly disable public key authentication :

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
set send_human {.6 .1 1.6 .1}
eval spawn $argv
match_max 100000
expect {
   -re "LOGIN@(\[0-9A-Za-z_\\-\\.\]+)'s password: "
    { sleep 0.6 ; send -- "PASSWORD" ; sleep 0.1 }
interact
```

Use constructs like `[lrange $argv 0 $argc]` if you need only part of the `$argv`

**Perl Answer**

Use `system 'script.exp' $path` to call `script.exp` from a `perl` script, assuming use `chmod`, etc., roughly like DeVadder said sans the quotes.  Or use `exec` if your `perl` script wishes to terminate.  Run `man perlfunc` to read about perl commands.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, So how should I call like  expect script.exp /x/y . where /x/y is the path?

Comment: I need to call this script in a perl script like this --            expect script.exp. I need to pass this argv as following --expect script.exp /x/y/z. Can i do like that?

Comment: DeVadder's comment answered that already, but I've updated this answer to elaborate.